# Angularjs and bootstrap datetimepicker

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I am trying to integrate a datetimepicker into my Angular form validation.  Everything works fine so far, but it does not seem to respond to the click of the button to bring up the calendar at all.  I have followed the example here : http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/.  Here is my code, the most relevant part is here :

```
<div class="control-group" ng-class="{error: form.BirthDate.$invalid}">
    <label class="control-label" for="BirthDate">{{'_BirthDate_' | i18n}}</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input id="BirthDate" name="BirthDate" title="BirthDate" type="text" ng-model="user.BirthDate" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" bs-datepicker required>
        <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="datepicker"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></button>
        <span ng-show="form.BirthDate.$dirty && form.BirthDate.$error.required">{{'_BirthDateRequired_' | i18n}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the whole page looks like this :

```
    <h2>Add User</h2>

<form name="form" id="form" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="control-group" ng-class="{error: form.UserName.$invalid}">
        <label class="control-label" for="UserName">{{'_UserName_' | i18n}}</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" ng-model="user.UserName" id="UserName" name="UserName" title="UserName" required ng-minlength="6" ng-maxlength="20" ng-unique="main.Users.Username" />
            <span ng-show="form.UserName.$dirty && form.UserName.$error.required">{{'_UserNameRequired_' | i18n}}</span>
            <span ng-show="form.UserName.$dirty && form.UserName.$error.minlength">{{'_UserNameLength_' | i18n}}</span>
            <span ng-show="form.UserName.$dirty && form.UserName.$error.maxlength">{{'_UserNameLength_' | i18n}}</span>
            <span ng-show="form.UserName.$dirty && form.UserName.$error.uniqueusername">{{'_UserNameUnique_' | i18n}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group" ng-class="{error: form.FirstName.$invalid}">
        <label class="control-label" for="FirstName">{{'_FirstName_' | i18n}}</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" ng-model="user.FirstName" id="FirstName" name="FirstName" title="FirstName" required ng-minlength="1" ng-maxlength="50" />
            <span ng-show="form.FirstName.$dirty && form.FirstName.$error.required">{{'_FirstNameRequired_' | i18n}}</span>
            <span ng-show="form.FirstName.$dirty && form.FirstName.$error.minlength">{{'_FirstNameLength_' | i18n}}</span>
            <span ng-show="form.FirstName.$dirty && form.FirstName.$error.maxlength">{{'_FirstNameLength_' | i18n}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group" ng-class="{error: form.Surname.$invalid}">
        <label class="control-label" for="FirstName">{{'_Surname_' | i18n}}</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" ng-model="user.Surname" id="Surname" name="Surname" title="Surname" required ng-minlength="1" ng-maxlength="50" />
            <span ng-show="form.Surname.$dirty && form.Surname.$error.required">{{'_SurnameRequired_' | i18n}}</span>
            <span ng-show="form.Surname.$dirty && form.Surname.$error.minlength">{{'_SurnameLength_' | i18n}}</span>
            <span ng-show="form.Surname.$dirty && form.Surname.$error.maxlength">{{'_SurnameLength_' | i18n}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group" ng-class="{error: form.Password.$invalid}">
        <label class="control-label" for="Password">{{'_Password_' | i18n}}</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" ng-model="user.Password" id="Password" name="Password" title="Password" required ng-pattern="/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{6,20}$/" />
            <span ng-show="form.Password.$dirty && form.Password.$error.required">{{'_PasswordRequired_' | i18n}}</span>
            <span ng-show="form.Password.$dirty && form.Password.$error.pattern">{{'_PasswordLengthAndAlphanumeric_' | i18n}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group" ng-class="{error: form.ConfirmPassword.$invalid}">
        <label class="control-label" for="ConfirmPassword">{{'_ConfirmPassword_' | i18n}}</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" ng-model="user.ConfirmPassword" id="ConfirmPassword" name="ConfirmPassword" title="ConfirmPassword" required ng-pattern="/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{6,20}$/" match-password="Password" />
            <span ng-show="form.ConfirmPassword.$dirty && form.ConfirmPassword.$error.required">{{'_ConfirmPasswordRequired_' | i18n}}</span>
            <span ng-show="form.ConfirmPassword.$dirty && form.ConfirmPassword.$error.pattern">{{'_PasswordLengthAndAlphanumeric_' | i18n}}</span>
            <span ng-show="form.ConfirmPassword.$dirty && !form.ConfirmPassword.$error.pattern && !form.ConfirmPassword.$error.required
                                                            && form.ConfirmPassword.$error.passwordmatch">{{'_PasswordsMustMatch_' | i18n}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group" ng-class="{error: form.EmailAddress.$invalid}">
        <label class="control-label" for="EmailAddress">{{'_EmailAddress_' | i18n}}</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" ng-model="user.EmailAddress" id="EmailAddress" name="EmailAddress" title="EmailAddress" required ng-pattern="/^(?!.{51})([a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)$/" ng-unique="main.Users.EmailAddress" />
            <span ng-show="form.EmailAddress.$dirty && form.EmailAddress.$error.required">{{'_EmailAddressRequired_' | i18n}}</span>
            <span ng-show="form.EmailAddress.$dirty && form.EmailAddress.$error.pattern">{{'_EmailAddressInvalid_' | i18n}}</span>
            <span ng-show="form.EmailAddress.$dirty && form.EmailAddress.$error.uniqueemailaddress">{{'_EmailAddressUnique_' | i18n}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group" ng-class="{error: form.BirthDate.$invalid}">
        <label class="control-label" for="BirthDate">{{'_BirthDate_' | i18n}}</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input id="BirthDate" name="BirthDate" title="BirthDate" type="text" ng-model="user.BirthDate" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" bs-datepicker required>
            <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="datepicker"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></button>
            <span ng-show="form.BirthDate.$dirty && form.BirthDate.$error.required">{{'_BirthDateRequired_' | i18n}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group" ng-class="{error: form.City.$invalid}">
        <label class="control-label" for="City">{{'_City_' | i18n}}</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" ng-model="user.City" id="City" name="City" title="City" required ng-maxlength="50" />
            <span ng-show="form.City.$dirty && form.City.$error.maxlength">{{'_CityLength_' | i18n}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions">
        <button ng-show="form.$valid" ng-click="save()" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
        <a href="#/" class="btn">Cancel</a>
    </div>
</form>

<script src="../../../Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="../../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.js"></script>
<script src="../../../Scripts/angular-strap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../../Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<link href="../../../Content/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Do I need to add something to my app.js? Currently I only have this related to the datetimepicker :

```
//You can use the global $strapConfig to set defaults
app.value('$strapConfig', {
datepicker: {
language: 'fr',
format: 'M d, yyyy'
}
});
```

EDIT : The issue was as JQuery Guru suggested, I needed to inject the angularstrap directive into my app.js.  It now works but the validation does not work as it should at all.  It does work when I click on a date in the calendar, but when I manually enter data it does not validate properly.  For example, entering text still gives the required validation message, and there is no pattern validation at all.

```
<

div class="control-group" ng-class="{error: form.BirthDate.$invalid}">
        <label class="control-label" for="BirthDate">{{'_BirthDate_' | i18n}}</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input id="BirthDate" name="BirthDate" title="BirthDate" type="text" ng-model="user.BirthDate" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" bs-datepicker required ng-pattern="/^(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\/(0[13578]|1[02])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)\/(0[13456789]|1[012])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\/02\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|(29\/02\/((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$/">
            <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="datepicker"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></button>
            <span ng-show="form.BirthDate.$dirty && form.BirthDate.$error.required">{{'_BirthDateRequired_' | i18n}}</span>
            <span ng-show="form.BirthDate.$dirty && form.BirthDate.$error.pattern">{{'_BirthDateInvalid_' | i18n}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inject the angularstrap directive in your apps.js below is the example:

```
angular.module('Myapp', ["$strap.directives"]);
```

Here is the working code:

http://plnkr.co/edit/QAxwgLSWQaYbGzkzeu4g?p=preview

and in left panel click on app.js to see

and also in your HTML page you need added reference for apps.js

```
<html ng-app="Myapp">
```

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was missing, I figured it out shortly before your post.  The other issue I have with this is that the validation does not work as it should do (see edit above).  If you have any ideas that would be awesome.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be forgetting to include the dependencies for the datepicker :
[bootstrap-datepicker.js](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/vendor/bootstrap-datepicker.js) and [bootstrap-datepicker.css](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/vendor/bootstrap-datepicker.css)